# createToken Function Works Locally but Fails After upload on Cpanel in Lravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

> hello world! I have been upload my Laravel project on file Manger in Cpanel , before I do that everything was going well , but after I upload the project and when I make login or new registration ,that an error appears saying:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;expires_at&#039; in &#039;field list&#039; (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, `expires_at`, `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (token, e4188216cb3aedae4c8490310e7217138f62e65273b6aa9883f2d85ab62b3016, [&quot;*&quot;], ?, 17, App\Models\User, 2023-11-27 09:38:25, 2023-11-27 09:38:25)) in file /home/myrout/myprojectname?vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 822
```

Note:*the error didn't exit when I work in localhost *

this code I try in **user controller **

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $fields = [
            "name" => "required",
            "phone" => "required|unique:users",
            "password" => "required",
            /*
* be careful !!!
* don't delete those two lines those tables of database
* ------------------------------------------------
             * 'type_id'=>"exists:type_of_users,id",
            'university_id'=>"exists:universities,id",
* -------------------------------------------------
*/
            'gender',
            'type',
            'university',
            'email'

//            "type"=>"required|exists:type_of_user,id",

//            "token" =>"required"
        ];
        $valid = Validator::make($request->all(), $fields);
        if ($valid->fails()) {
            $msg = $valid->messages()->first();
            return $this->fail($msg);
        }

        $password = app('hash')->make($request->password);
        $phone = $request->phone;
        $name = $request->name;
        $gender = $request->gender;
        /*
     * be careful !!!
     * don't delete those two lines those tables of database
     * ------------------------------------------------
        $type = $request->type_id;
        $university = $request->university_id;
     * -------------------------------------------------
     */

        $type = $request->type;
        $university = $request->university;
        $email = $request->email;
//        $token = $request->token;


//        $numbers = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
//        // Generate 4 random alphabetical characters
//        $characters = str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
//        $alphabets = substr($characters, 0, 4);
//        // Combine numbers and alphabets
//        $random_password = $numbers . $alphabets;

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $name,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'password' => $password,
            'gender' => $gender,
            'email' => $email,
//            'random_password' => $random_password
            /*
* be careful !!!
* don't delete those two lines those tables of database
* ------------------------------------------------
          'university_id'=>$university,
            'type_id' => $type,
* -------------------------------------------------
*/
//            'token' =>$token
            'type' => $type,
            'university' => $university
        ]);
        $user = User::find($user->id);
//        $user['token'] = Str::random(60);

        $user['token'] = $user->createToken('token')->plainTextToken;
        return $this->success(new UserResource($user));
    }
```

**api file**

```
//Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
//    return $request->user();
//});
Route::post('/user/register', [UserController::class,'register']);
```

in my database I don't have a field token , I just put it in model of user
the one thing more , I think the Cpanel couldn't to execute `createToken('$name')` command line, that look like the version of Laravel is not same another version in local project .

Comment: *"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column"* - did the `expires_at` column exists in the `personal_access_tokens` table? did you miss a migration?

Comment: no expires_at not exists but when I put it now the another error appear :` Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column &#039;expires_at&#039; cannot be null (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, `expires_at`, `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) `

Comment: yeah, gotta fix it with migration not duct tapes.

Comment: It work <3 , thank you man , I spend many hours to try solve this issue , you are the best